# How do I use xmlstarlet to edit xml files with similar structure elements?

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

I'm trying to edit an XML file that looks something like this:

```
<Item>
    <rasd:AllocationUnits>hertz * 10^6</rasd:AllocationUnits>
    <rasd:Description>Number of Virtual CPUs</rasd:Description>
    <rasd:ElementName>8 virtual CPU(s)</rasd:ElementName>
    <rasd:InstanceID>1</rasd:InstanceID>
    <rasd:Reservation>18000</rasd:Reservation>
    <rasd:ResourceType>3</rasd:ResourceType>
    <rasd:VirtualQuantity>8</rasd:VirtualQuantity>
    <vmw:CoresPerSocket ovf:required="false">8</vmw:CoresPerSocket>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <rasd:AllocationUnits>byte * 2^20</rasd:AllocationUnits>
    <rasd:Description>Memory Size</rasd:Description>
    <rasd:ElementName>8192MB of memory</rasd:ElementName>
    <rasd:InstanceID>2</rasd:InstanceID>
    <rasd:Reservation>8000</rasd:Reservation>
    <rasd:ResourceType>4</rasd:ResourceType>
    <rasd:VirtualQuantity>8192</rasd:VirtualQuantity>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <rasd:Address>0</rasd:Address>
    <rasd:Description>SCSI Controller</rasd:Description>
    <rasd:ElementName>SCSI Controller 0</rasd:ElementName>
    <rasd:InstanceID>3</rasd:InstanceID>
    <rasd:ResourceSubType>VirtualSCSI</rasd:ResourceSubType>
    <rasd:ResourceType>6</rasd:ResourceType>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <rasd:Address>1</rasd:Address>
    <rasd:Description>IDE Controller</rasd:Description>
    <rasd:ElementName>VirtualIDEController 1</rasd:ElementName>
    <rasd:InstanceID>4</rasd:InstanceID>
    <rasd:ResourceType>5</rasd:ResourceType>
  </Item>
```

Inside the `<item>` element that contains:

```
<rasd:Description>Memory Size</rasd:Description>
```

I want to edit(or add, if it doesn't exist) the element titled `<rasd:Reservation>`

I can handle the conditionals to determine if an element exists or needs to be changed, but I'm having problems figuring out how to have xmlstarlet select the correct element, when some of those elements have duplicate names.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your XML file looks like

```
<Items xmlns:rasd="foo" xmlns:vmw="bar" xmlns:ovf="baz">
    // your content here
</Items>
```

Then you can use do

```
xmlstarlet ed -N rasd=foo \
              -u '//Item[rasd:Description = "Memory Size"]/rasd:Reservation' \
              -v 12345 \
  file.xml
```

Comment: That's not what my XML looks like though. It looks like what I gave in the example.

Comment: If you don't have a single root element and if you don't declare your name spaces, then you don't have XML. And if you don't have XML then you can't use xmlstarlet.

Comment: Ahhhh, I see. Thanks for explaining! Besides some grep hackery and sed magic, is there another way I could parse each section in my example?